# What are the sub-types of the Zoans and fighting styles?

Tags: one-piece

What are the sub types of the Zoans and fighting styles? I've been searching for lists but haven't seen any.

Comment: What is meant by 'sub types'? I initially thought you were asking for the 'series' which refers to the common prefixes for different models of similar fruit (e.g. ushi ushi no mi, model: giraffe and ushi ushi no mi, model: bison are both part of the ushi ushi no mi (Ox Ox fruit) series). But this could also refer to 'sub-classes' of zoan fruit which includes the basic ones, ancient zoans, mythical zoans, etc. Also what does fighting style mean? Most zoan users don't have a named fighting style / use one independent of their fruit (e.g. Mr. 2's Okama Kenpo is not reliant on his devil fruit)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the subtypes of zoan type devil fruits [here](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Zoan).
Though for fighting styles you will have to go to individual wiki pages of the devil fruits to see that as a user can have a specific fighting style that he combines with his devil fruit, be it any type.

For example though it is not a zoan type devil fruit fighting style of Ace and Sabo is completely different for the Mera Mera no Mi. Same applies for the Zoan type DF. So I would suggest to go to the link mentioned above which also has list of devil fruits and read it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

From how far I am, not totally sure, but the Zoan fruits are supposed to where you can turn into a certain animal. how they fight depends on what you get.